# Should deduction guide for std::optional be applied when passing std::ref(value)?

Tags: c++, templates, option-type, c++17

### Background

I'd like to run some functions in sequence, short-circuiting when one of them succeeds. They all have the same return type, are mostly zero argument callables (lambdas with captures). To identify success, the function returns non-empty optional. The thing is that sometimes those functions return references, in which case writing

```
return std::optional{some_reference};
```

will be UB. But, it seems like doing

```
return std::optional{std::ref(some_reference)} ;
```

is not. GCC 9 happily [compiles](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VTt3HA6fwaVOfksa)  that. Though clang 7 [doesn't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bQ8x9zNP8k2ucjhf).

---

### Full code:

```
#include <optional>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 12;
    auto job = [](const int& y)
    {
        return std::optional{std::ref(y)};
    };
    auto value = job(x);
    x = 25;
    std::cout << *value << '\n';
}
```

### Question

Which one of them is right?

---

I believe the code should compile, because class template argument deduction should be applied and `std::reference_wrapper<int>` deduced.

Comment: It looks like deduction guides aren't fully implemented in libc++.  P0433R2 is still listed as [in progress](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in OP is well-formed and should yield an `optional<reference_wrapper<int>>`.

This is [llvm bug 34650](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34650). A simpler example demonstrating the problem is:

```
std::optional o(42);
```

gcc allows it (with `o` being a `std::optional<int>`), clang does not.

Comment: So any `xvalue` will not be deduced correctly? Oh, it seems like it affects other value categories too.

Comment: @Incomputable I don't understand the question? What won't be deduced correctly?

Comment: The type parameter of the `std::optional`. Am I using wrong words?

Comment: @Incomputable I don't know what you're asking. Do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: It seems like writing `std::optional{lvalue}` will work correctly in clang, but something like `std::optional{foo()}` will not, as well as array arguments. Accepting your answer anyway. Thanks.